# Force Show Menu button (Soft keys)

Tags: buttons, pac-rom

I've updated to the latest nightly build of Pacman ROM, and then updated it through recovery (wiped: cache and Dalvik Cache) and the system boot up and everything works great but there are 2 exrea menu buttons (softkeys, on the left side of the screen, and on the right side) and actually they are a little bit dimmed. Is there amy solution to remove this extra menu soft keys?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting for them in Interface > Navigation bar. You should read the instructions there and then proceed. It's similar to CyanogenMod.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I have found that option and even disable it, but still the problem is there. It looks like there is a problem with the ROM.

Comment: maybe , plz do me a favor , If my answer helped you , vote up plz :)